# How to escape special characters in a string?

Tags: bash

Assuming `$file` holding a value of a file name, say `Dr' A.tif`. In bash programming, how could I escape single quote and any other special character of the `$file` without removing the special character?

**Update on 9 July 2014**

As [request from @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141312/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-a-string#comment-228866), following code snippet that doesn't able to handle `Dr' A.tif`:

```
files=$(find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.[Pp][Dd][Ff]" -o -name "*.[Tt][Ii][Ff]")
echo "${files}" > ${TEMP_FILE}
while read file
do
   newfile=$(echo "${file}" | sed 's, ,\\ ,g') ## line 1
done < ${TEMP_FILE}
```

After I have tried out the [answer from @Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141323/72471) on `line 1`, it seems to work for me. But if I have file such as `Dr\^s A.tif`, `printf` command doesn't seem help, it shows me `Dr\^s\ A.tif`. If I manually try it on console like this:

`printf "%q" "Dr\^s A.tif"`

I will have this output:

`Dr\\\^s\ A.tif`

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: in what context are you expecting to use $file? or is this issue assigning the string with the special character to $file?

Comment: Actually the find command return me an array of file list. And then I loop through this file list into $file variable.

Comment: You've been given some correct answers here, but they are probably not the answers to the question that you're really asking. From your comment here, I strongly suspect that you're on the wrong track. We can't help you much because you keep not showing your code. I do however recommend that you read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) as background. **Show your script and explain what you want to do.**

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `printf` builtin with `%q` to accomplish this. For example:

```
$ file="Dr' A.tif"
$ printf '%q\n' "$file"
Dr\'\ A.tif

$ file=' foo$bar\baz`'
$ printf '%q\n' "$file"
\ foo\$bar\\baz\`
```

From the bash documentation on `printf`:

> ```
> In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1)
> and printf(3), printf interprets:
>
>  %b       expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
>  %q       quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
>  %(fmt)T  output the date-time string resulting from using FMT as a format
>           string for strftime(3)
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work with certain cases .e.g. when you need to preserve double-quotes.

Comment: @user3467349 it works just fine with quotes. I'm betting you're trying something like `printf '%s' "foo"`. You need to understand how argument parsing works in the shell first. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation #2 happens before #6.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this string printed with `printf` and no other manipulations `It doesn't have a: ""`

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with `printf`. Your issue is that you don't want the shell to parse your string. In order to do that, you have to pass your input to the shell in a way where it doesn't even try to parse it. One way to do this would be `read -r -p 'input: ' && printf '%q\n' "$REPLY"`, and provide the input when prompted.

Comment: Provide input while prompted won't work well in a shell script, neither is it speedy even interactively. Hence my above comment about this being a limited / sub-optimal solution.

Comment: As i've said several times now. Not knowing how how to pass raw data to the shell isn't an issue with `printf`. Perhaps you should ask a question rather than critiquing a solution that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: You can use `cat <<EOF;` (as I wrote below) which seems preferable to me since it will handle edge-cases which your answer doesn't support. I should point out that *How to escape special characters in a string?* is a generic search-phrase that will cause people to stumble on this question and it makes sense to provide an answer that will cover cases which fit the title (even if it's not exactly what OP was asking).

Comment: For a more modern version of this answer without `printf`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817504/442022 .

Answer (score 4):

Try:-

```
file=Dr\'\ A.tif
echo $file
Dr' A.tif
```

or

```
file="Dr' A.tif"
echo $file
Dr' A.tif
```

or if the string contains a double quote:-

```
file='Dr" A.tif'
echo $file
Dr" A.tif
```

There are good tutorials on escaping and quoting on the net.  Start with [this one](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape any file names you are handling in a script. Escaping is only necessary if you want to put a file name as a *literal* in a script, or to pass several file names as a single input stream to another script.

Since you're looping through the output of `find`, [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) is one of the simplest ways (!) to **handle every possible path**:

```
while IFS= read -r -d ''
do
    file_namex="$(basename -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
    file_name="${file_namex%$'\nx'}"
    do_something -- "$file_name"
done < <(find "$some_path" -exec printf '%s\0' {} +)
```

Comment: I think you need another `<` before the `<(`

Comment: Instead of futzing to make cmdsub+basename work for weird names, why not just `${REPLY##*/}` -- or even `IFS=/ read -r -d '' -a split; ... "${split[${#split[@]}-1]}" ...`

Answer (score -1):

quick and (very) dirty

```
find . | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/'
```

Answer (score -2):

A lot of these answers,
including the top-voted one using `printf "%q"`,
will not work in all cases without additional manipulation. 
I would suggest the following (example below):

```
cat <<EOF
2015-11-07T03:34:41Z app[postgres.0000]: [TAG] text-search query doesn't contain lexemes: ""
EOF
```

Comment: Excuse the n00b question but can you elaborate on how you would actually use this to escape characters in a string? If I copy the code you write into my terminal it just prints

2015-11-07T03:34:41Z app[postgres.0000]: [TAG] text-search query doesn't contain lexemes: ""

...nothing is escaped.

Comment: That's literally the point, all of the special characters *are* interpreted as literal characters not for their special meaning. Try to *echo* "the above string" instead to see the difference.

Comment: This answer would be an appropriate answer for e.g. [quoting - How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296141/how-to-use-a-special-character-as-a-normal-one-in-unix-shells) , but not this question where the "string to be escaped" is the output of a command, not hard coded.